# Sending image over network c++

Tags: visual-c++

I have problem sending image over the network. but I keep getting error 
Sending From Client to Server

```
( "msvcr110d.dll" Access violation writing location 
 mov     [edi],edx           ; store one more dword c++)
```

Any idea what is wrong.

Platform:
Windows 7
Visual studio c++ 2012 Express
C++

Send & Receive Message

```
(
 string ReceiveMyMessage(SOCKET s1)
{

exception e;
try
{
ZeroMemory(szbuffer,strlen(szbuffer));

if((ibytesrecv = recv(s1,szbuffer,100,0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    throw "Receive error in server program\n";

return ((string) szbuffer);
}
catch(exception e)
{
```

cout<<"Seems Client is Down!\n(SendMyMessage) Error While trying      to executing recv command!"<

Client Code:

```
void SendStreamFile()
 {
_get_printf_count_output();

struct stat myFileState;
int Filesize = 0;
char * myDATA;
FILE *f = fopen(FileName.c_str(),"rb");
Filesize = (int) myFileState.st_size;
myDATA = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * Filesize);
fread(myDATA,1,Filesize,f);
fclose(f);

SendMyMessage(to_string( Filesize));
char * ptr;
string strToSend = "";

for (int x = 0; x < Filesize; )
{
    ptr = &myDATA[x];
    strToSend.assign(ptr,20);
    Sleep(100);
    //cout << strToSend <<endl;
    SendMyMessage(strToSend);
    x = x + 20;
    cout << x << " - " << Filesize <<endl;
}

SendMyMessage("*D*");
free(myDATA);
 }
```

Server Code:

```
void ReceiveClientFileStream(string FileName, SOCKET s1)
 {

string Fsize = ReceiveMyMessage(s1);

   int Filesize = 0;
Filesize= atoi(Fsize.c_str());


char * myDATA;
myDATA = new char[Filesize];
   cout << strlen(myDATA) << Filesize <<endl;
//SendMyMessage(to_string( Filesize),s1);
//char * ptr = &myDATA[0];
string str = "";

   //   ZeroMemory(myDATA,Filesize);
do
{
    str = ReceiveMyMessage(s1);
    cout << str << endl;
    if (str.find("*D*") == string::npos)
strcat(myDATA,str.c_str());
    else
        {   
strcat(myDATA,str.substr(str.length()-3, str.length()).c_str());
            break;
    }

}while(1);
FILE * fil;
fil = fopen(FileName.c_str(),"wb");
fwrite(myDATA,sizeof(char),strlen(myDATA),fil);

free(myDATA);

}
```

Comment: Start by paying attention to the warnings that the compiler sends; for example, myFileState in SendStreamFile() is used without initialization and therefore the file length you use is wrong.

Comment: The problem the compiler does't give any error or warnings. and I cant find the source of the error. I changed thinking about memory allocation issues but it should be fine. I am suspecting the server can't handle the amount of data being sent(could it be ASCII or something coz the cout << strlen(myDATA) << Filesize <<endl; Filezie output 442d3). On the order hand seems the server or client grouping messages then it send them. if i read last line from a file then executed send it will send it with the *D* which is another problem.

Comment: Forgot to mention something, the server receive some of the messages then randomly crash like 1st time it crashed like 2000 message where sent to it next time it was less and other timme more

Comment: Is the server or the client crashing? Please attach the call stack, it would be really helpful.

Comment: About strlen(myDATA): myDATA is uninitialized at that point (apart from being allocated), so you're reading the length of the garbage in the memory.